# Fit FabricJS text into an image (speech bubble)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm currently trying to create a speech bubble using FabricJS. The user should be able to write text into it and the text should be inside the speech bubble. I'd post an image, but I don't have enough reputation, yet. So this is basically about fitting text into an image.

What I'm doing is load the image, then create the text and put them both into a group, so the user can move them around together.

However, the problem is: When the text is too long, it'll continue to go outside the bubble instead of having linebreaks.

What I could do now is check the width of the text, and if it is too much, add some line breaks by figuring out words where to use it. I doubt that'd work pretty good though and it isn't very efficient.

Is there another solution for this?
Thank you!

Comment: We have text-wrapping planned for the future — https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/187 Didn't have time to get to it yet. Hopefully in the next few months unless someone helps.